# Number theory related to rings

Tags: number-theory

Why it is true that every odd number r that is not equivlant to p mod p has a odd number $s$ s.t

$rs\equiv 2p-1 \mod 2p $

My first thought is that i should have an inverse for $r$ in the ring so i can write.
$s\equiv r^{-1} (-1) \mod 2p $ but im not sure what in number theory tells me that $r^{-1} $ exists?

Where p as always in number theory is prime.

Comment: I suppose $p$ is a prime, can you please confirm?

Comment: Ofc p is prime.

Comment: If $r=2p$ this isn't true. You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @Faust Edit your question for clarity. People shouldn't have to read the comments to know that $p$ is prime.

Comment: My book literally says in the beginning it reserves the use of p and q only for primes henceforth on like the second page. Thought it was standard in number theory my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $p$ is a prime, and that not just $r\ne p$ but $p\not\mid r$...

$r^{-1}$ exists because $r$ (being odd) is coprime with $2p$. Thus, $1=rs+2pt$ for some $s,t\in\mathbb Z$ ([Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)), or, reducing modulo $2p$, $1\equiv rs\pmod{2p}$.

Comment: @ajotatxe I know... I hope the OP will clarify their post. The OP's statement is true if $p$ is prime and $p\not\mid r$ and I believe that is what they think... but I am happy to delete my answer if they thought of something else.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, we can take $-1/r=-r^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2p$, since we know that $r\not\equiv 0\bmod 2$ and $r\not\equiv 0\bmod p$ by assumption.

Comment: This I already know but abstract algebra is not a pre-req for this class there must be a number theory solution to this problem.